# How do I resolve this "no such file or directory" hook error?

Tags: juju, magento

I am trying to write a charm for Magento but running into an issue.

Here is the source for charm
https://github.com/MoT3rror/Magento-Charm

The install works perfect. Still needs a lot of work but works.

I having trouble with database-relation-joined hook to run through. It is saying the file doesn't exist but I am able to edit it on that machine so it there. I gave the file execute privileges. I am stuck why I got the error.

Steps deploying charm

```
juju bootstrap
juju deploy mysql
juju deploy --repository=/home/$USER/charms/ local:precise/magento
juju add-relation mysql magento
```

Error:

```
2013-11-21 05:48:51 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:517 joining relation "magento:database mysql:db"
2013-11-21 05:48:51 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:543 joined relation "magento:database mysql:db"
2013-11-21 05:48:56 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:348 running "database-relation-joined" hook
2013-11-21 05:48:56 ERROR juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:350 hook failed: fork/exec /var/lib/juju/agents/unit-magento-0/charm/hooks/database-relation-joined: no such file or directory
2013-11-21 05:48:56 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:423 ModeAbide exiting
2013-11-21 05:48:56 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:421 ModeHookError starting
2013-11-21 05:48:56 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:418 want resolved event
2013-11-21 05:48:56 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:412 want forced upgrade true
2013-11-21 05:48:56 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:523 no new charm event
```

List of the files on the server.
https://github.com/MoT3rror/Magento-Charm/blob/master/list%20of%20files.jpg

Also is there a way to update a charm without destroying the environment and bootstrapping the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I checked out your charm the hook permissions were:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 1058 Nov 21 10:39 database-relation-joined`

So you probably forgot to commit the files after setting your hooks to executable.

Running `chmod +x *` in your hook directory and then re-committing/pushing should solve your problem.

Comment: No luck. Still getting same error.

Comment: Ok then we are going to need more information, can you edit your question to include the steps you are taking to bootstrap your environment and deploy the charm plz

Comment: I included the steps in my question. Also I just tried changing the file to just have juju-log command and it works. Going to step through my code and see which line is giving me trouble now.

Comment: After checking out your branch I followed my previous suggestion then followed your steps and the hook files executed as expected but with the error `Database Name cannot be empty` from the `database-relation-joined` hook. So it looks like the original issue was related to the permissions but that exposed another issue further down.

Comment: I recreated the database-relation-joined with the same contents and ran that command and it worked. Now to see why database is null. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)